# How to write mutually exclusive methods and Dispose?

Tags: c#, idisposable, mutual-exclusion

*In short -- think of Threading.Timer and its specialized method `Dispose` taking `WaitHandle` as parameter. In my case I have to make one step further, I have to write regular, parameterless, yet awaiting, `Dispose`.*

#### The story

Let's say I have a type `Foo` implementing such interface:

```
interface IFoo : IDisposable
{
  void Action1();
  Task Action2Async();
}
```

The user of type `Foo` can call `Action1` and at the same time `Action2` and at the same time `Dispose`.

When the `Dispose` is called it should mark the current instance as disposed and wait for all current actions to end. Then it should proceed with disposing.

Regular methods should check if the instance is disposed and if yes, they should silently quit or throw an exception -- the point is they should not proceed with actual actions.

#### The idea

I figured out, well a bool flag and `CountdownEvent` should suffice -- when method is called I increase the counter, on exit I decrease it, and when implementing `Dispose` I simply call `Wait` -- this will tell me if all methods finished executing.

But here is the catch, `CountdownEvent` is `IDiposable`, so I should dispose it too, so I won't be able to use it in methods.

OK, so I write custom type wrapping `CountdownEvent` and since I need some memory barrier I could use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. But... `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is `IDisposable` as well.

Sure, I could use regular `lock` but methods calls and Dispose call ratio is N:1.

#### Question

So how to write mutually exclusive methods and Dispose?

Comment: That goes against what is expected of any implementation of the interface `IDisposable`. If the caller calls Dispose then the instance should cleanup and return control to the caller. It is the responsibility of the caller to ensure that `Dispose` is only called when it is done using that instance. You will see this in any implementation of `IDisposable`. As an example see `EFS`'s `DbContext`, call a long running query using `ToListAsync` (but do not await the resulting `Task`) and then call `Dispose` on the `DbContext` and see what happens.

Comment: Calling Dispose() is *optional*.  You do so when it is convenient to call it.  Most typically with the *using* statement or a class' own DIspose method.  This is far beyond convenient, so far that it is just plain wrong.  Let the finalizer do its job it was made to do.

Comment: @Igor, yes, in real world the consumer of my type will behave properly, but in real world I have to deal with what I have. Since I cannot change the consumer, I have to make changes in my code.

Comment: @HansPassant, type `Foo` `Dispose` **will be** called. Since it will be called I have to dispose all objects I have inside, correct? In order to do so, I have to wait until all started actions are finished.

Comment: @HansPassant woah there; there's no way that I'd say that calling Dispose() is optional - any missing call to Dispose() is IMO a bug (with the possible exception of types where it is explicitly known to not matter, like `MemoryStream`)

Comment: So you are adding this to code that is already out there being used by consumers you have no source control over? Note tho following in the documentation: [IDisposable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) - *It is a breaking change to add the IDisposable interface to an existing class. Because pre-existing consumers of your type cannot call Dispose, you cannot be certain that unmanaged resources held by your type will be released.*

Comment: @Igor, I have to implement `IFoo` (provided by consumer, it is `IDisposable` for years), period, that's it. You can lecture me all day, it does not change a thing.

Comment: Don't get what is a problem with `CountdownEvent`. First `Wait` on it in dipose, then dispose event itself.

Comment: even if Dispose "seems" to be optional in some case like "MemoryStream" call it! because implementation of an object can change.

Comment: Then I have no idea what the problem is. You state you can't change the behavior of the caller BUT if you are adding functionality (`IFoo`) so the caller's code has to change if they want to take advantage of it. So let the `IDisposable` cleanup and do what it should do according to the contract. The code documentation should state that the caller should await the result of any returned Tasks before calling Dispose but that should be obvious.

Comment: @Evk, here is no problem, but how do you access then bool flag `isDisposed` in regular methods? You have to have some memory barrier, you cannot use `CountdownEvent` because you just disposed it. So you have to use something else -- what?

Comment: @Igor, `IFoo` is not mine, `Foo` is -- so I have to write internals of `Foo` in such way, that if consumer calls `Action`+`Dispose`, `Dispose` will block until `Action` is finished. Pretty similar as with `Threading.Timer` (see my remark on the top of the question).

Comment: If you need memory barrier - mark your boolean field as 'volatile' to ensure that changes are visible to all threads. Hard to say more without actual code example.

Comment: @Evk, good point, thank you, the code is actually the answer to my problem, so there is none, only thinking :-) But I forgot about one thing when writing comment, since `CountdownEvent` will be disposed, the logic in method has to be reversed -- first checking the flag, then using `CountdownEvent`. So this means, this code has to be atomic (to avoid call to `Dispose` jumping between).